# Unit testing with monodroid and visual studio 2010

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.android

Has anyone managed to run unit tests created with vs2010 on an android device? Is there any other solution to unit testing android applications when using monodrod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the [Andr.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Andr.Unit) library, which provides a runner for NUnit tests that can run either in the emulator or on an Android device. There is also the [monodroid-unittest](https://bitbucket.org/mayastudios/monodroid-unittest/wiki/Home) library that provides support for Visual Studio tests.